# gmail contact fetching source code for iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone App where i have to fetch Gmail contact list to send request to add friend.I am not getting good tutorial to implement Google API.If anybody done can u post the code.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a site where people write your applications, we can help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use GData for objective-c;

```
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction
```

You need to check out from svn and use this project and integrate into your project.

May this helping to lot.